# php sessions value get wiped after ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, session, request

I have a script where i set my uid and email sessions when a user logs in.

in 2 variables:

```
$_SESSION["uid"] = $user_id;//1,2,3 etc..
$_SESSION["email"] = 'my@email.com';
```

I have a feature where a user can post some data via ajax.
But when the data are sent to the server and the request is completed, then my email session's value gets wiped and that causes my user not to be able to do some actions.

I searched my whole script and i couldnt find any

```
$_SESSION["email"] = '';
```

after an ajax request is done or wherever else it might be.

any clues?

**EDIT:**
var_dump of _SESSION:

```
array(2) { ["email"]=> &string(0) "" ["uid"]=> &string(11) "91283921834" }
```

**SOLUTION:**
My host was showing 5.2.17 as default php version so i had to call

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

in my .htaccess file to make it see 5.3.5 as the live php version which removed the references and now its working fine.

Comment: it doesnt seem to get wiped which is weird

Comment: So with your AJAX call you start your session and the email is the only value not available?  Update your question with a var_dump of the _SESSION where the email is not set.

Comment: Wish I could help more, but I'd need to see a lot more of the code to try to debug it.  T9b's SO question might be something to try.

Comment: its weird that it happens only on live server and not in localhost.

Comment: @fxuser: You're making use of references/variable aliasing. Check the PHP version on live server and localhost. They should differ. I smell some call time pass by reference which has been deprecated and does not work any longer with `call_user_func_array` at least. Other stuff might vary as well. Check for warnings / notices in the live server PHP error log. You might need to enable those. [Call_user_func_array(), PHP 5.3 and Passing by Reference](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/call_user_func_array-php-5-3-and-passing-by-reference/)

Comment: localhost php version is 5.3.5 and server one is 5.2.17... looking into my code for the references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You somewhere assign a variable by reference to your session, you can see this with the `&` character in your `var_dump`:

```
array(2) { ["email"]=> &string(0) "" ["uid"]=> &string(11) "91283921834" }
#                     ^^^                     ^^^
```

A reference in PHP means, that in your case `$_SESSION['email']` has become an alias for some other variable. If that *other* variable is changed, `$_SESSION['email']` will change as well as it's only an alias.

So you not only need to look into your code where you change `$_SESSION['email']` but more importantly which parts makes it an alias and where the alias get changed as well.

It's just a guess but search for `&$email` or just `$email`. Look for functions that accept parameters by reference (`&$parameter`), return by reference or are called with parameters by reference.

Comment: i searched all functions and $_SESSION["email"] variables or anything related and couldnt find any "&" in a variable or a function parameter. could it be server php version that is 5.2.17 since my localhost is 5.3.5?

Comment: @fxuser: The difference in the PHP version between server and localhost is a sign for what I outlined in my answer. However, with what I have proposed it does not mean that it will actually help you to find the root cause. Look as well for dynamic function calls (the function name is dynamically build and/or the function call is made with `call_user_func*`. Additionally search for *any* `&`. Could be non-trivial to fix this though.

Comment: If that's healing, why not ;). And as the references have disappeared shows that the flaw in code isn't triggered any longer. Feel free to accept the answer if the hint was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `session_start()` at the top of each of your script in order to actually create a session

Place it just after the `<?php` tag

Comment: i do include my config.php which has my session start and db connection

Answer (score 0):

When I first started working with php sessions this sort of thing drove me crazy until I got the hang of them.

There are a couple of things you should note, the main thing is that your session cookie is the key, because it persists as long as you want it to.

Even though you start a session and the session cookie is set on one page each new page you send to the browser should still check to see if a session has been set.

As you mentioned that your using ajax I assume that one page (for example a form) gets processed through ajax, and the response is either back to the same page or a redirection. Where do you set your session? is it in theAjax handling script - or in the original form page?

If you redirect after a successful AJAX call think about what happens when your user hits "back". Do you want the same data to be displayed or will the form need to look new again?

I can't give you a specific answer without more information, bt I have an interesting question that might help.

[MY SO Question on sesssions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446081/php-sessions-working-very-well-but-somethings-bugging-me)

Comment: where do you mean where do i set the session?sessions are set when a user logs in.my form is a commnent form, so a user adds text, clicks submit and then ajax form processes it through a php page and sends back json data.I do not redirect, just send back the comment text.
by the time i submit the form and refresh the page, my session is wiped.

Comment: try echoing the session id on every page. You soon see if the session id remains the same across page or changes. If it changes, then you lose your session variables. Also try forcing your php ini to create the session from you domain by explicitly setting it in code `ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.yourdomain.com');`